# Exception thrown by Agent Spark Job Server

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-jobserver

I am trying to run Spark Job server on a multi node server.

I have set master="yarn-client" on the namenode

When I run server_start.sh
I get an error

`Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException`

The error is not coming due to used port. Port 8090 is free

Comment: It will be great if you can provide more information.  1) spark-jobserver.log , 2) spark master log, 3) yarn log

Comment: It was a version issue I was using 2 different versions of scala on the system